# s3cmd reporting Access Denied on user of account but not when using main account

Tags: amazon-s3

We have two AWS accounts. We are using s3cmd to backup data from one s3 bucket to another. 
The issue we have run into is this: The source bucket is public, and can be accessed by anybody without credentials. When we initiate the backup with s3cmd using one of the two master key pairs from the s3 bucket where want to put the backup files on it works flawlessly.

However, when we try to perform this same operation - this time using a user's key pair rather than the account's key pair (on the account where we are backing up the files to) we are given an access denied error.

**Here is the command we run:**
`s3cmd -c /root/.s3cfgBackup sync s3://oldbucket/news/ s3://newbucket/Videos/`

**Here is the policy on the user that gets access denied**

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::newbucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::newbucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help me resolve this access denied issue? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try changing the policy on that user this way:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::newbucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::newbucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::oldbucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::oldbucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
  ]
}
```